If AlCl3 has such a high lattice energy, why is it so soluble in organic solvents?
AlCl3 is well known to be relatively covalent, but doesn't solubility generally go down as lattice energy increases, (I.e born-haber cycle?)? However it's soluble in many organic solvents

Could you cite some references, please, to support your assertions?

Not all of the lattice energy has to be broken. When, let us say, sodium chloride is dissolved into water, all the sodium-chlorine bonds have to be broken, requiring energy which, in this case, is provided by strong ion-dipole interactions with water molecules. But in the case of aluminum chloride, with its covalent character, some of the bonds in the lattice structure are preserved, especially if the "molecules" are actually $\ce{Al2Cl6}$ dimers.
In addition and perhaps decisively, the Lewis-acidic aluminum chloride molecules can form covalent bonds with solvent atoms that provide an electron pair, which applies to a wide variety of solvents such as ethanol and chloroform where Wikipedia reports that aluminum chloride is "soluble". If we do not have the acid-base interaction the aluminum chloride solubility is more limited; the above Wikipedia source reports that aluminum chloride is only "slightly soluble" in benzene.
